# Ethernet doesn't work after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: networking

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04. The ethernet is now longer recognized. If I open Network from System Settings and click on Wired, it shows

```
Wired Disconnected - 1000 Mb/s
Hardware Address 00:90:F5:C7:69:B7
```

and the interface is "OFF". If I click "ON", it briefly displays the message "Connection failed" and shuts off immediately.
If I unplug the cable, the message changes to:

```
Wired Cable Unplugged
```

I have:

```
% lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(ethernet|network)"
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:7100]
        Kernel driver in use: jme
03:00.1 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 90)
--
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:0091] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN [8086:5201]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller [197b:2380] (rev 30)
```

I also tried:

```
% ifconfig eth0 down
% ifconfig eth0 up
% /usr/bin/sudo service networking restart
% /usr/bin/sudo service network-manager restart
```

I ran modprobe and got:

```
% sudo modprobe eth0
modprobe: FATAL: Module eth0 not found.
```